# Must the "default" case come last in a switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

In a switch statement in java, is it necessary that the "default" case be the last one? For example, can I do something like the following:

```
switch(x) {
case A: ....;
default: ....;
case B: ....;
}
```

Comment: Next time you come across a question like this, I recommend you try it out first.

Comment: Not sure why this is posted as a question when you can try it out yourself?

Comment: The JLS does not put any restriction where to put the `default` case as it's a `SwitchLabel` like any other. The only restriction is that you cannot have more than 1 `default` case in the same switch statement.

Comment: Of course I could try it out. I posted it as a question for the community. Geez.

Comment: Arrived here by Googling this question. Thanks @KelseyRider

Comment: I tried it myself but still googled this to see what others have to say about this.. Thank you @Kricket

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No.. But it is suggested to put it at the end to make the code more readable. The code shown below works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 5;
    switch (i) {
    default:
        System.out.println("hi");
        break;

    case 0:
        System.out.println("0");
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("5");
        break;
    }
}

O/P : 5
```

Comment: in some rare cases it could be more readable to place it first (or not last), e.g. if you have lots of switch statements that return a boolean (true/false) where you want the 1st return to be false and the 2nd true for consistency across all statements

Answer (score 6):

no, the default statement could also be the first one.

Answer (score 2):

It surely is not necessary, but beware it will behave a lot differently in case fall-through is used.

```java
int[] test = {0,1,5,23,24};
for (int t: test) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Running test: %s", t));
    switch(t) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println(String.format("Match: %s", 0));
    default:
        System.out.println(String.format("Match: %s", "default"));
    case 23:
        System.out.println(String.format("Match: %s", 23));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Running test: 0
Match: 0
Match: default
Match: 23
Running test: 1
Match: default
Match: 23
Running test: 5
Match: default
Match: 23
Running test: 23
Match: 23
Running test: 24
Match: default
Match: 23
```

This simply speaking means:

- if there is an exact (non-default) `case` defined **after** `default` case it is matched first instead of the `default` one
- if there is not, then the `default` case understandably makes all tested values fall through from itself down

Observe especially the test for `23` - the result would be different if `case 23` and `default` was swapped (both will be matched then).

Demo: https://ideone.com/LyvjXQ

Answer (score -2):

The *default* statement can be placed anywhere inside switch statement body

```
   switch (i) {

          // the default statement can be placed anywhere inside the switch statement body

    }
```