# How switch works when a case has not been selected

Tags: java

I saw this code in the OCA Java 8 exam study guide which confused me.

```
int dayOfWeek = 5;
switch(dayOfWeek) {
  case 0:
    System.out.println("Sunday");
  default:
    System.out.println("Weekday");
  case 6:
    System.out.println("Saturday");
    break;
}
```

The book says it prints Weekday and Saturday.

Why is this?

I thought the case had to be found to get selected since it is 5 is is not selected so nothing should happen.

Comment: Because there is a `default` clause.

Comment: if you don't put break, it continues sequentially all the following cases and also the note @luizfzs said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As no case matches value of `dayOfWeek`, the **default** case is executed: printing `"Weekday"`

As the **default** case has no `break`, the next case that follows it is also executed, until it reaches end of switch or a break:  printing `"Saturday"`

Comment: Pardon my misunderstanding but when no case matches is default always executed? So after executing default it would do all of the remaining cases because there is no break?

Comment: Yes, it will do it so sequentially. If default is the last case then no other case will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: because you "fall" through cases. If you want to not fall through, you have to use `break`.

So the default is really that you execute all cases following the first match - until you hit the first `break` statement.

Comment: If we're going to be ultra-precise, it is "execute all statements after the matching case label, until you hit the first statement which completes abruptly" - it doesn't have to be a `break`, it could be a `return`, an explicit `throw`, or something which causes an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the cases for which you want to explicitly do something.
Otherwise, for all the remaining cases they will be handled in `default`.

Also, check the related [Must the "default" case come last in a switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024813/must-the-default-case-come-last-in-a-switch) for more explanation.

And as others have also pointed here, if you don't put break then it will go through all the remaining cases too without fail till it encounters a `break`.